# Using JWT for multiple users

Tags: api, jwt

I'm new to API, I'm mainly doing various plugins and backend stuff for our small CMS. I would like to be able to handle some tasks via endpoints.

I want to use JWT for user authentication. I understood the part where the server creates a token with data for the user and signs it with a secret code. I also understand the validation of the incoming token in the request.

So now to my problem. It is desirable that only authorized users can use the API. And they can't all have the same secret key, then security would be pointless.

Our CMS is a public project and running on different hosting servers, I'm not sure it has HTTPS enabled. So it is not safe to send the password as part of the payload. So I came up with the idea of generating each authorized user their own secret key, which they sign with their `login` token containing the username.

The server receives the token, reads the username from it, and finds the secret in the database against which to validate the received token. It then creates a server token for the user signed with the server secret key, which the user will then send in the request header.

Is this the right idea, is this solution applicable? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you use rsa to do the initial secret exchange over the insecure channel?

Comment: The idea is that the user will just send a payload like this `{"username": "johndoe"}` in the initial token and sign the whole thing with his secret key that was assigned to him. Well, the server will look up the secret key for `johndoe` in the db and verify the authenticity. I think this is safe even for non-HTTPS cases.